# Find the anchor element where the value is equal to the hash in the URL

Tags: jquery, hash, find, anchor, addclass

How do you find the anchor element where the `name=` value is equal to the hash in the URL, then add `open` class to the next div element?

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); //Puts hash in variable, and removes the # character
    console.log(hash);
    // Find the anchor element where the value is equal to the has in the URL, then add '.open' class to the next div element.
    $("a[name=$hash]").addClass('open'); //WRONG SYNTAX! How do I write this?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    if (location.hash === "#hash") {
        //Logic
     $("#divid").addClass('open');
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the value is harcoded, i need `#divid` to be a variable e.g.  `hash`

Comment: my think is `$("a[name=$hash]).addClass('open');` but i kno wthis is not the right syntax.

Comment: Code only answers are a no no for SO, please add explanation

Comment: `$hash` should be `hash`

Comment: like this `$("a[name=" + hash + "]").next().addClass('open');`